# Windows ASP.NET redirection

Tags: asp.net, redirect

We have a few sites that are all controlled via one CMS, even though they have their own domain name. They are all hosted under the one account.

I want to set the default page to index.html on one of the domains via web.config

So for example, with abc.com i want it to default to abc.com/index.html but leaving the other domains as they are.

While I can set the default to index.html it seems to break the other sites, as they redirect back to this on every occasion.

Comment: [IIS URL Rewrite](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) (IIS 7+) should help, otherwise for IIS 6, [URL Rewriter](http://urlrewriter.net/) helped me a lot in the past.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to wrap redirect rule with [location](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b6x6shw7%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) element and specify your domain in the `path` attribute.

**UPDATE**
I think it should be something like this:

```
<configuration>
...
<location path="http://abc.com">
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <clear />
        <add value="index.htm" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</location>
...
</configuration>
```

Comment: Unfortunately makes no difference.

Going to abc.com shows the index.html file, but going to def.com shows the same index.html file

Comment: Well, you can try to specify `defaultDocument` for def.com the same way, because `index.html` is one of the default values after `Default.htm` and `Default.asp(x)`. So, if you haven't such files in directory, it'll be redirected to `index.html`.